# How to randomly pick rows while optimizing for the sum of a different measure

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have to randomly pick rows from a table. I am doing this by using the `rand()` function inside the `qualifying row` statement. I want the random picks to collectively add up to 100 or close to 100 but cannot be greater than that (Qty field below). Below is an illustration of the input table

```
CID Qty
ABC 5
BCD 10
CDE 50
DEF 60
EFG 40
```

In this particular case there is a convenient 60 & 40 (from CDE and DEF). In their absence, I want the final results to be 50+40 (CDE + EFG)

I am not looking for any kind of fit. The selection of the rows will be completely random and the only criteria is that the randomly selected rows add up as close to 100 as possible.

Comment: please confirm - you are not looking for perfect or good fit, you just looking for any random fit - no matter how close it will be to 100 - right? asking because usually such cases are looking for the best fit! so please confirm your goal

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant Added that to the question. I am not looking for best fit. Just that the randomly selected rows should add up as close to 100 as possible

Comment: Sorry for insisting  - "as close as possible" and "random" actually two mutually exclusive criterias. It is either or! anyway - will see how those two can be married :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am not looking for best fit. Just that the randomly selected rows should add up as close to 100 as possible

Consider below approach

```
select 
  format('%s (%s)', string_agg('' || qty, ' + '), string_agg('' || cid, ' + ')) random_pick,
  sum(qty) total
from (
  select *
  from your_table
  where true 
  qualify sum(qty) over(order by rand()) < 100
)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Note: each time you run above  - you will get different (random) output as it is expected in your question. Below are outputs of few runs

[image]

[image]

[image]